# Fetch users from Azure AD

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I can't figure out why my loop isn't working at all. I have successfully connected to my clients directory and I am able to fetch some users. I have followed the [PHP instructions](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-php-graphapi-web/tree/master/PHP). But this tutorial doesn't include example for fetching all users only the default page size of 100 users.

I am aware of the skipToken ([explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options#PagingSupport)) but for some reason I am not been able to get it work with my loop.

Basically first I define an array, and two sub arrays.

```
 $myArray = array();
 $myArray['skipToken'] = "";
 $myArray['users'] = "";
```

Then I'll perform the first fetch so I can get skipToken and bunch of users that come along.

```
 require_once("GraphServiceAccessHelper.php");
 $users = GraphServiceAccessHelper::getFeed('users');
```

Pushing values into already existing arrays.

```
 $myArray['skipToken'] = $users->{'odata.nextLink'};
 $myArray['users'][] = $users->{'value'};
```

Now they are filled with information. Now its time to loop!

```
 for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
    if($myArray['skipToken'] != ""){
      $skipToken = $myArray['skipToken'];
      require_once("GraphServiceAccessHelper.php");
      $users = GraphServiceAccessHelper::getNextFeed('users', $skipToken);
      $myArray['skipToken'] = $users->{'odata.nextLink'};
      $myArray['users'][] = $users->{'value'};
    }
 }
```

Console fires up from error, that points to loop skipToken defining part:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$odata.nextLink

$myArray['skipToken'] = $users->{'odata.nextLink'};
```

Comment: Have you inspected the page being returned? Can you see the skip token there?

Comment: @juunas Yes I can see the Skip token, but for some reason its empty when loop starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out.

First I had to remove everything before actual token.

```
$skipToken = $users->{'odata.nextLink'};
$skipToken = substr($skipToken, strpos($skipToken, "=") + 1);
```

Then inside the loop use that get new **skipToken** and do the same like above:

```
$new = GraphServiceAccessHelper::getNextFeed('users', $skipToken);
if(isset($new->{'odata.nextLink'})){
  $skipToken = empty($new->{'odata.nextLink'});
} else{
  break;
}
$skipToken = substr($skipToken, strpos($skipToken, "=") + 1);
$myArray['tokens'] = $skipToken;
$myArray['users'][] = $new->{'value'};
```

By checking if `'odata.nextLink"` exists I can easily stop the while loop since lastpage doesn't contain `'odata.nextLink'`.

```
if(isset($new->{'odata.nextLink'})){
  $skipToken = empty($new->{'odata.nextLink'});
} else{
  break;
}
```

I am appending each 100 user array to another array that I can call easily use it outside PHP.