# Pagination integration with Azure AD Graph API PHP Sample

Tags: php, azure-active-directory

I have successfully connected to my clients directory and I am able to fetch users from azure Active directory but just not all of them. I have followed the following [PHP instructions](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-php-graphapi-web) however this tutorial doesn't include example for fetching all users but only the default page size of 100 users.

I am aware of the skipToken ([explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options#PagingSupport)) but I am not able to figure out how this should be integrated within my loop. here below is the page content.

```html
<?php
    //Include menu options applicable to all pages of the web site
    include("PhpSampleTemplate.php");
?>

<HTML>
    <head>
        <title>
            Administration Page For Users
        </title>
    </head>

    <BODY>
        <h1>
            Administration Page For Users
        </h1>  
        <a href="CreateUser.php"><b>Create And Add A New User</b></a>    
        <br/><br/>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
            <th>Display Name</th>
            <th>User Principal Name</th>
            <th>Object ID</th>
            <th>Account Enabled</th>        
            <th>Edit Link</th>
            <th>Delete Link</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
    $users = GraphServiceAccessHelper::getFeed('users');
                foreach ($users as $user){
      if ($user->{'accountEnabled'} == 1)
        {
         $accountEnabled = 'True';
        }
        else
        {
         $accountEnabled = 'False';
        }
      $editLinkValue = "EditUser.php?id=".$user->objectId;
      $deleteLinkValue = "DeleteUser.php?id=".$user->objectId;
      echo('<tr><td>'. $user->{'displayName'}. '</td><td>'. $user->{'userPrincipalName'} .'</td>');
      echo('<td>'. $user->{'objectId'}.'</td>');
      echo ('<td>'. $accountEnabled.'</td>'); 
      echo('<td>' .'<a href=\''.$editLinkValue.'\'>'. 'Edit User' . '</a></td><td>'
        .'<a href=\''.$deleteLinkValue.'\'>'. 'Delete User' . '</a></td></tr>');
    }
 ?>    

        </table>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919435/fetch-users-from-azure-ad) is a very similar issue here but it didn't help much, perhaps I am doing something wrong.

Could anyone please assist?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I do a demo on my side. You could refer to the following code.

**Modify getFeed function in GraphServiceAccessHelper.php**

```
 public static function getFeed($feedName){
                // initiaze curl which is used to make the http request.
                $ch = curl_init();
                // Add authorization and other headers. Also set some common settings.
                self::AddRequiredHeadersAndSettings($ch);
                // set url 
                $feedURL = "https://graph.windows.net/".Settings::$appTenantDomainName."/".$feedName;
                $feedURL = $feedURL."?".Settings::$apiVersion;
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $feedURL);
                //Enable fiddler to capture request
                //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
                // $output contains the output string
                $output = curl_exec($ch);                               
                // close curl resource to free up system resources 
                //curl_close($ch);                                                                               
                while(true){
                $jsonOutput = json_decode($output);
                $users = $jsonOutput->{'value'};
                foreach ($users as $user){
                          $userArr[] = $user;
                         }
                 if(isset($jsonOutput->{'odata.nextLink'})){
                                                            $nextLink = $jsonOutput->{'odata.nextLink'};
                                                            $feedNextURL = "https://graph.windows.net/".Settings::$appTenantDomainName."/".$nextLink."&".Settings::$apiVersion;
                                                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $feedNextURL);
                                                            $output = curl_exec($ch);
                                                            }
                                                            else{
                                                                   curl_close($ch); 
                                                                    break;
                                                            };
                                                    };
                // There is a field for odata metadata that we ignore and just consume the value
                return $userArr;
            }
```

**Modify page content**

```
 <?php
     $users = GraphServiceAccessHelper::getFeed('users');
     $total = count($users);
     $limit = 50;
     $pages = ceil($total / $limit);
     $page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
                                                           'options' => array(
                                                                    'default'   => 1,
                                                                    'min_range' => 1,
                                                            ),
                                                )));
     $offset = ($page - 1)  * $limit;
     $start = $offset + 1;
     $end = min(($offset + $limit), $total);
     // The "back" link
     $prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<a href="?page=1" title="First page">&laquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '" title="Previous page">&lsaquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&laquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&lsaquo;</span>';

      // The "forward" link
      $nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '" title="Next page">&rsaquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . $pages . '" title="Last page">&raquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&rsaquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&raquo;</span>';

      // Display the paging information
      echo '<div id="paging"><p>', $prevlink, ' Page ', $page, ' of ', $pages, ' pages, displaying ', $start, '-', $end, ' of ', $total, ' results ', $nextlink, ' </p></div>';

      $subUsers = array_slice($users, $offset, $limit);
      foreach ($subUsers as $user){
                                      if ($user->{'accountEnabled'} == 1)
                                                           {
                                                                 $accountEnabled = 'True';
                                                           }
                                                           else
                                                           {
                                                               $accountEnabled = 'False';
                                                           }
                                                           $editLinkValue = "EditUser.php?id=".$user->objectId;
                                                           $deleteLinkValue = "DeleteUser.php?id=".$user->objectId;
                                                           echo('<tr><td>'. $user->{'displayName'}. '</td><td>'. $user->{'userPrincipalName'} .'</td>');
                                                           echo('<td>'. $user->{'objectId'}.'</td>');
                                                           echo ('<td>'. $accountEnabled.'</td>'); 
                                                           echo('<td>' .'<a href=\''.$editLinkValue.'\'>'. 'Edit User' . '</a></td><td>'
                                                            .'<a href=\''.$deleteLinkValue.'\'>'. 'Delete User' . '</a></td></tr>');
                                                       } 
      ?>
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I changed the code to reflect the above however I am getting the following error: 

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$value in D:\test\GraphServiceAccessHelper.php on line 26

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\test\GraphServiceAccessHelper.php on line 27

Line 26 and 27 are as follows:

$users = $jsonOutput->{'value'};
foreach ($users as $user){

Comment: could you please show the value of $output as well $jsonOutput?